# Querying a JSON String in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, parsing

I have a table that is a single column made up of a JSON string. The JSON has multiple key pairs, and is a string because it is the raw table.

One of the keys is `"Ticket"` and has dollar amount values. I am not certain if prices are in `__.__` format, or just `____`. I want to query the column to return me the entire string if this `"Ticket"` ends in a 6, as in 96 cents, or 66 cents, etc.

This is my query:

```
SELECT json FROM tablename
WHERE json RLIKE '%"TICKET": "___6",%'
OR json RLIKE '%"TICKET": "__._6",%'
```

This currently returns as blank.

How can I get the entire string if the dollar amount ends in a 6 (as in 6 cents)?

Comment: Tag your RDBMS (sql server, oracle, etc) and its version.

Comment: Without knowing the data it is hard to tell what's wrong with this, but those underscores are requiring the data to have an exact number of characters.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search strings you are using are what you would use for [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

So you could use LIKE :

```
select * from tablename
where (json LIKE '%"TICKET": "___6"%' or json LIKE '%"TICKET": "__._6"%')
```

Or a [RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) with a regex:

```
select * from tablename
where json RLIKE '"TICKET":[ ]*"[0-9.]+6"'
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I was too tired today to rember that I should have changed it to a regex instead of LIKE wildcard. Thanks.